# One Password for All?

Tags: civicontribute, wordpress

When someone signs up or registers, we need to generate a username and password. But for the password, we would like one (1), the same password for everyone.

Is this possible? And if so, how do I set it up?

Also for importing people in, and for new sign ups.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

There is no setting to have the same password for all people signing in. If you have a CiviCRM installation that is accessible from outside your domain in any way I would strongly advocate you do NOT allow the same password for everyone. All security and integrity recommendations would mention that you do NOT allow all your users to have the same password?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes, exactly what I thought..just wondered if there was a way... The password generated by civicrm, is a string of numbers and characters, and we can enable login via email address or username, so password isn't so important. Good though especially for security measures. A very old, outdated system, had used the same password for nearly 9000 people. What is the best way to import these people into civicrm, and how do I generate a password for them?

Comment: You can import them from the Import function? And generating a password confuses me: do all contacts need a password? CiviCRM does not generate passwords, your CMS (Drupal, Joomla! or WordPress) might?

Comment: Yes, all imported contacts need a password. Wordpress, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Admin > Users and Permissions > Synchronize Users to Contacts
ie at path wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/synchUser&reset=1 you will see the option "Synchronize Users to Contacts: CiviCRM will check each user record for a contact record. A new contact record will be created for each user where one does not already exist. Do you want to continue?"
You can use this to generate the WP user for each record. Then you should be able to send them out an email telling them how to use their email to 'request new password'

Note the last instruction is based on Drupal know how, not WP but hope it works for you.

Afaik the integration will only take across an email address for the user. Hence if you have used a WP plugin to keep name and address, or a Drupal user fields/profile, then you will need to either use sql query or Export that additional data from WP/Drupal and import based on matching with the civi contact record based on matching the email address

Comment: Thank you so much peterdnz. As a "test" I tried to import 4 users with full details, contact, address, name, username, etc. and it asked me to map to the tables in the database. All went well, but the ONLY item actually in was the email address and nothing more. Any ideas? Also, how do I ensure the email will actually go out to each user, do I use civimail or covicampaign?

Comment: You can use civimail or you can just find in a Search and 'send an email' depending on how many you have to do

Comment: I don't understand your other comment about 'import 4 users with full details'.

Comment: As a test I tried to import contacts, with full details, mailing address, phone, first name, last name, email, etc --- and the only thing imported into the contact, individual was a single email address, not everything else.

Comment: I don't understand because this ticket had nothing to do with importing. Perhaps you need to ask that as another question. My answer was about how to give a WP user account for an existing Civi Record. If my answer did help with that step can you pls +1 and/or accept as that is what makes StackExchange work well. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I tried that as well, sync a user to contact, and it only gave me a email address as well, not full details. Any ideas why?

Comment: I don't understand - WHERE does it give you these things? In Civi? In WordPress. Sorry for caps but struggling to figure how to help and perhaps you need to be a bit more verbose ;-)

Comment: Hello, in Wordpress, using CiviCrm, Contacts.... When I used the WP Membership Sync plugin, my understanding was that everyone from WP users and all their details would automatically go into a Individual user, as a contact in CiviCrm. The only thing that moved over was their email address.  It happened the exact same way importing directly into the system, without the plugin.

Comment: Do you mean there is a different plugin to what I pointed out at Admin > Users and Permissions > Synchronize Users to Contacts

Comment: Yes, I have tried both, and both do not work. If I only use the one you suggest, it also only brings in email addresses,nothing more.

Comment: this is what i don't understand. "bring in' from what/where? if you have a wordpress user, with an email, then it will create a civi contact with an email. if you have some 'other' data in wordpress, then no I do not believe it will pull that in and you will need to either use sql, or export and import it in to civicrm. I don't think you have explained sufficiently what data you have where for me to help.

Comment: ok i updated my original answer in case that helps clarify ;-)